# Perl Date Comparison Query

Tags: perl, date, string-comparison

I'm trying to output "not ok" if the date provided within an input file is greater than one day from "today" using Perl version 5.8.8.

Initializing with "./code.sh < test.txt" works fine, when test.txt contains the following data:

```
07/02/2020 08/02/2020
```

When I rehash the code below to try an use "today's date" as a variable, and only have one date within the input file I get the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at code.sh line 27, <> line 1
```

Working code (with two dates in the input file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

#my $date = localtime->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
#print "$date";

my $format = '%d/%m/%Y';

while (<>) {
   chomp;

         my ($str1, $str2) = split;
#        my ($date, $str2) = split;

#  my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date, $format);
   my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);
   my $dt2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, $format);

   #  print "$date / $str2 ";
  print "$str1 / $str2 ";

     if ($dt2->julian_day - $dt1->julian_day ==1) {

         print "ok\n";

     } else {
         print "not ok\n";
         }
}
```

Broken code (with one date within the input file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = localtime->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
print "$date";

my $format = '%d/%m/%Y';

while (<>) {
   chomp;

#        my ($str1, $str2) = split;
         my ($date, $str2) = split;

   my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date, $format);
#  my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);
   my $dt2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, $format);

     print "$date / $str2 ";
 # print "$str1 / $str2 ";

     if ($dt2->julian_day - $dt1->julian_day ==1) {

         print "ok\n";

     } else {
         print "not ok\n";
         }
}
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: There are a few typos in this code. Your datetime format definition is wrong (`$d` where you mean `%d`) and you've missed a colon in `Time::Piece` a few times. When I fix those, your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please pay more attention when you  type your code, your sample had a few miss-types

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%d/%m/%Y';
my $date   = localtime->strftime($format);

say "Today is: $date\n";

my @str_dates = <DATA>;

chomp(@str_dates);

my $date1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str_dates[0], $format);
my $date2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str_dates[1], $format);

my $days_diff = $date2->julian_day - $date1->julian_day;

my $msg = ($days_diff == 1) ? "ok" :"not ok";

say "$date2 :: $date1 => $msg";
say "$date2 :: $date1 =  $days_diff day(s) apart";

__DATA__
07/02/2020
08/02/2020
```

Output

```
Today is: 07/02/2020

Sat Feb  8 00:00:00 2020 :: Fri Feb  7 00:00:00 2020 => ok
Sat Feb  8 00:00:00 2020 :: Fri Feb  7 00:00:00 2020 =  1 day(s) apart
```

NOTE: I would recommend if you use:

- Windows OS
  [notepad++](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable)
- Linux OS [vim](https://www.vim.org/)

vim better use with options: *syntax on, ai,ts=4,sw=4*

Comment: Apologies, I've corrected the typo's.  I forgot to mention I'm working with Perl v5.8.8 with no option to upgrade the system.  I'll update the question to reflect this also.